# awk print first occurrence after match

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to print a portion of a text file between two patterns, then return only the first occurrence. Should be simple but I can't seem to find a solution.

cat test.html

```
if (var == "Option_1"){
  document.write("<td>head1</td>")
  document.write("<td>text1</td>")
}
if (var == "Option_2"){
  document.write("<td>head2</td>")
  document.write("<td>text2</td>")
}
if (var == "Option_1"){
  document.write("<td>head3</td>")
  document.write("<td>text3</td>")
}
```

This prints all matches:

```
awk '/Option_1/,/}/' test.txt
```

I need it to return only the first, i.e.:

```
if (var == "Option_1"){
  document.write("<td>head1</td>")
  document.write("<td>text1</td>")
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Never use range expressions as they make trivial jobs very slightly briefer but then require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions for even slightly more interesting tasks. Always use a flag:

```
$ awk '/Option_1/{f=1} f{print; if (/}/) exit}' file
if (var == "Option_1"){
  document.write("<td>head1</td>")
  document.write("<td>text1</td>")
}
```

Comment: I didn't know we can simply use `if(/pattern/)`

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks Ed.

Comment: @anishsane - yes `/foo/` is shorthand for `$0 ~ /foo/` wherever you use it in a condition context.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that there are no `}` inside the if blocks.

Using GNU sed :

```
sed -n '/Option_1/{:a N;s/}/}/;Ta;p;q}' file
```

Here's how it works :

```
/Option_1/{     #search for Option_1
    :a          #create label a
    N;          #append next line to pattern space
    s/}/}/;     #substitute } with }
    Ta;         #if substitution failed, jump to label a
    p;          #print pattern space
    q           #exit
}
```

Comment: Simpler: `/Option_1/ {:a; p; /}/q; n; ba}`

Comment: You need the -n option, otherwise all the other lines will be printed if let's say you search for Option_2

Comment: Haha, yeah i made the same mistake than you trying to simplify my answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding somewhat to Ed Morton's answer, you can write it again to work for some nested if condition or if there exist any other pair of braces inside the if statement (eg. braces for for loop).

```
awk '/Option_1/{f=1} f{ if(/{/){count++}; print; if(/}/){count--; if(count==0) exit}}' filename
```

output for:

```
if (var == "Option_1"){
  document.write("<td>head1</td>")
  if (condition){
    //code
  }
  document.write("<td>text1</td>")
}
if (var == "Option_2"){
  document.write("<td>head2</td>")
  document.write("<td>text2</td>")
}
if (var == "Option_1"){
  document.write("<td>head3</td>")
  document.write("<td>text3</td>")
}
```

is:

```
if (var == "Option_1"){
  document.write("<td>head1</td>")
  if (condition){
    //code
  }
  document.write("<td>text1</td>")
}
```

`count` will keep count on number of starting braces and will print the statement until the count reaches 0 again.

My input might be different from question but the information may be useful.

Comment: You're confusing awk and shell syntax. You don't need pairs of parens around arithmetic ops in awk `((count+=1))`, a simple `count++` will do it. Your script will fail for any except the first block, try it for `/Option_2/`.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for figuring out my mistake. I have updated my answer and now it seems to work correctly for any option.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/Option_1/,/}/ !d;/}/q' YourFile
```

- delete everything not inside your delimiter and quit after last line of it (so 1 section only)
- for non GNU sed, replace the `;` after `d` by a real new line

Answer (score 1):

You can do,

```
awk '/Option_1/,/}/{print; if ($0 ~ /}/) exit}' test.txt
```

This exits after printing the first match

Comment: Yeah I tried that one... but it only returns the first 'line' of the first occurrence. Thanks, though.

Comment: Sorry, I revised it. Try it again.

Comment: This will not work if you search for `Option_2` in the sample file

Comment: Notice you had to duplicate the end condition `/}/`. Never use range expressions.